# what php version Pandorafms5.1 sp4 will work with Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: php

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 to the machine.Now I want to install **Pandorafms 5.1 sp4** for that I installed Apache server, MySQL  and php5.6. By default Ubuntu 16.04 supports to php7. When installing Pandorafms it gives me this error.

```
(Reading database ... 219547 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pandorafms.console_5.1SP4.deb ...
Unpacking pandorafms-console (5.1SP4) over (5.1SP4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pandorafms-console:
 pandorafms-console depends on php5; however:
  Package php5 is not installed.
 pandorafms-console depends on php5-snmp; however:
  Package php5-snmp is not installed.
 pandorafms-console depends on php5-gd; however:
  Package php5-gd is not installed.
 pandorafms-console depends on php5-mysql; however:
  Package php5-mysql is not installed.
 pandorafms-console depends on php5-xmlrpc; however:
  Package php5-xmlrpc is not installed.
 pandorafms-console depends on php5-curl; however:
  Package php5-curl is not installed.
 pandorafms-console depends on php5-ldap; however:
  Package php5-ldap is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package pandorafms-console (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pandorafms-console
```

I want to know which version of PHP I should install.

Comment: I thought you said you installed `php5.6`?

Comment: Please run `sudo update-alternatives --display php` and post the result into your question

Answer (score 0):

PandoraFMS is not compatible with PHP7 according to 
[Pandora community forum](https://pandorafms.com/forums/thread-8070.html)